# UWP build error - Duplicate Entry and Conflicting values for resource

Tags: c#, uwp

Adding an external dll in simple "Hello World" `UWP` project is giving the two errors shown in the screenshot below:

**NOTE**: There are many online posts on such errors but most involve complex cases (adding images, using Telerik, ComponentOne tools etc) but this is just a simple text project just to test why adding a dll from a class library that does not do any image processing etc.is causing this issue.

**Error** [Click on the image to make it more readable]:

[image]

**UPDATE**:

My `MainPage.Xaml` file:

```
<Page
    x:Class="UWP_Test4.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:UWP_Test4"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="695,614,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Button_Click"/>
        <RichEditBox Name="rtbTest" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="532" Margin="0,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1480"/>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: Can we see your XAML?

Comment: @AmirNo-Family Per your request, `XAML` added.

Comment: Your xaml code looks correct, The better way that you could provide us [mcve].

Comment: And you could share more detail about your *external dll*.